# Bordermatrix in MathJaX

Tags: feature-request, mathjax

It would be nice to be able to make matrices with column and row names using `\bordermatrix{}`

Producing something like this:

[image: bordermatrix]

This has also been requested on [Cross Validated meta](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/809/bordermatrix-in-mathjax)

But it hasn't been added yet I think. Any tips for making this?

Comment: Did you read the comments to the post you linked? Peter Krautzberger tells you what to do if you want MathJax to do it...

Comment: One of the few times a "status-not-our-problem" tag would be appropriate :-P

Comment: `$
\bordermatrix{&\left|\alpha\alpha\right\rangle&\left |\alpha \beta \right \rangle &\left|\beta\alpha \right \rangle &\left |\beta\beta\right\rangle\cr
\langle\left \alpha\alpha \right |&- \frac{1}{2}{}\omega _{A}-\frac{1}{2}\omega _{B}+\frac{1}{4}J& 0 &0&0\cr
\langle\left \alpha\beta \right |&0 & -\frac{1}{2}{}\omega _{A}+\frac{1}{2}\omega _{B}-\frac{1}{4}J& \frac{1}{2}J&0 \cr
\langle\left \beta\alpha \right|&0&\frac{1}{2}J&\frac{1}{2}{}\omega _{A}-\frac{1}{2}\omega _{B}-\frac{1}{4}J&0\cr
\langle\left \beta\beta \right|&0&0&0&\frac{1}{2}{}\omega _{A}+\frac{1}{2}\omega _{B}+\frac{1}{4}J
}$`